# jQuery slideToggle jumps

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I can not find what is problem with such an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/gth5qeqq/4/

```
$('select').parent().on('click', function (){
    $(this).find('ul').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

It jumps when I click the option. But, It's ok when the options number is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to jump to the left because the length of the menu makes the vertical scrollbar appear. You can fix this by restricting the height of the `ul` that contains the options and setting `overflow-y` so that it can scroll. Try this:

```
.select_wrapper .select_inner {
    /* your current CSS... */
    max-height: 150px; /* amend this height as needed */
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gth5qeqq/6/)